# List item and MVC4 styling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have a set of list items that I am using that need to be a link and http post back to the controller. I had to do some custom styling on them, just not sure the best way to handle it. This is what I have:

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="listItems">
    @foreach (var item in Model.shares)
    {            
        <li class="outerListItem">
            <div class="accountLI">@item.description</div>
            <div class="currentLI">@item.Num1</div>
            <div class="availableLI">@item.num2</div>
        </li>            
    }        
</ul>
```

Usually I would use @Html.ActionLink(text, action, controller), however I need the 3 'columns' to be formatted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` has an overload which can accept html attributes to be injected in the final link tag, consider the following example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(text, action, controller,new {@class="MyClass")}
```

the previous line should render an anchor, with a class called MyClass like the following

```
<a href="LINK_URL" class="MyClass">text</a>
```

Note that in case you needed to render any extra html5-like data attributes (data-age), you will need to replace the dash with an underscore, and the Razor engine (the engine responsible of rendering the final HTML in the ASP.NET MVC framework) should understand it.

Consider the following example

```
@Html.ActionLink(text, action, controller,new {@class="MyClass", data_age=33)}
```

This will render an anchor like this:

```
<a href="LINK_URL" class="MyClass" data-age="33">text</a>
```

Comment: can you evaporate more on this, I can't get the real problem here, I'm all listening.

Comment: So in each list item, I have 3 divs that are styled spaced out to fill the screen. I want to be able to keep that spacing and styling and be able to click the list item.